# ReactJS: access to fetch has been blocked by CORS policy

Tags: reactjs, cors

I am getting the following error in my ReactJS project:
"access to fetch has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource
If an opaque serves your need set the request mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled."

This is how I send requests to the backend:

```
export const sendRequest = async ( endpoint = '' ,
 method = 'GET', body) => {
    const response = await fetch(`${url}${endpoint}`, {
        method,
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
        body: JSON.stringify(body)
    })
    const data = await response.json();

    return data;
}
```

I thought first that it is a backend problem but I checked there, found backend CORS Access is enabled for the same headers and client.

Any modifications should I do to the function above??

Answer (score -1):

There an npm module called `cors`. You can install it in your backend. If you are using ExpressJS, you can just use cors as an middleware using `app.use(cors())`. With the equivalent header set in the request, it should work